# Film where boy's parent reveal their alien selves to him

Tags: story-identification, movie

I never saw the full film, just a uk trailer, dated maybe about 1990. I thought at the time "I'm gonna watch that" but then the years intervened.

I've had a search through this site but no joy.

What I recall is this kid aged approx eleven is gaping in horror because he learns his parents (step-parents maybe) are shape changing aliens/ demons

They proceed to flip through a few changes while laughing at his reaction, one that stayed in my memory was **"you called us butt-heads, well look at this!"** and both then change their heads into people with big butts from the neck up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like [Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_(film)) (finished 1989 and released 1992). Here is the butt head scene:

(“Well son, I guess you were right: I AM a butthead!”)

Comment: what terrible, terrible movie. just awful. i wish i had not seen this. thought January 6 was bad -- this is worse.