# Horror movie about a family of monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember that this is something like Cronenberg films. It seems that there the guy accidentally spied on his sister in the shower and saw that she had breast on her back, and then the whole family turned out to be monsters. It seems that the family gathered in the evening for dinner, and then they tried to catch the guy. Monsters were horribly ugly.

Comment: This is extremely brief is there anything else you can remember? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) for some pointers. For example, any more details of the story? When did you watch this? Approximately when was it made?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot more likely to be [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209528/film-where-boys-parent-reveal-their-alien-selves-to-him).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[***Society (1989)***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098354/)

> An ordinary teenage boy discovers his family is part of a gruesome orgy cult for the social elite.

The girl's body is actually contorted so that the top/bottom halves don't match.

Slightly NSFW Image & Video

> [image]

A french version of the scene in question is on youtube.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_(film))

> Society is a 1989 American body horror film directed by Brian Yuzna, and starring Billy Warlock, Devin DeVasquez, Evan Richards, and Ben Meyerson. Its plot follows a Beverly Hills teenager who finds his wealthy parents are part of a gruesome cult for the social elite.